# Why IP header variable declarations are swapped depending on Byte Order

Tags: c, linux, ip

The ip.h file on my Ubuntu distribution has the following struct iphdr copied below. Can anyone explain why the order of the variables ihl and version changes depending on the byte order. According to my understanding "endianess" would matter if there were more than one byte, but in this case these two (ihl and version) combine to make a single byte. Therefore, being little or big endian should not effect the ordering of the bits within a byte.

```
struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    u_int8_t tos;
    u_int16_t tot_len;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t check;
    u_int32_t saddr;
    u_int32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

Comment: The types are ints (of various sizes), not bytes.  The fact that you use bitfields doesn't change that.  Plus, you can't guarantee (portably) how the bitfields are stored internally. You could use unsigned char instead if CHAR_BIT is suitable.

Comment: However, it matters that the order in which the declarations are made changes depending on the byte order. This matters when I receive a packet and want to map it to this struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implementation- (psABI-) specific, but what's going on is that the bit order of bitfields within a byte or word, in practice on the relevant implementations, matches the byte order of bytes within a word. Thus, in order for these members to occupy the same bit positions independent of which type of system is being used, their order is swapped based on endianness.